# Yes/No :Is the ideal generated by $\{ 3 , \sqrt 6 \}$ in the Ring $\mathbb{Z}[ \sqrt 6] $is both maximal and prime Ideal.?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Yes/No  :Is the   ideal generated by $\{ 3 , \sqrt 6 \}$ in the Ring  $\mathbb{Z}[ \sqrt 6] $is both maximal and prime  Ideal.?

My attempt :I think yes , Take  $I=\{ 3 , \sqrt 6 \}$ and we know  that $3$ is prime , that $\mathbb{Z_3}$ is finite field , so i think  this will  be both prime  and maximal by the  theorem that  in finite Ring   every Ideal  is  both  prime  and maximal

Is  its  true ?

Comment: "in finite Ring every Ideal is both prime and maximal" is not true.

Comment: For the record, $\Bbb Z[\sqrt6]$ is very much infinite.

Comment: $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{6}]/(3,\sqrt{6}) \cong \Bbb Z_3$

Comment: Note: maximal ideals are prime. And, as the quotient by the ideal is the finite $3$ element ring, which is a field, the claim is true.